# Let new users of StackExchange sites read the FAQ

Tags: feature-request, login, stackexchange-2.0, site-faq

I noticed that when I went to the Programmers Beta that I couldn't even see the FAQ, it kept wanting me to login.  How do I know I want to get involved with the site (if not coming from Area51) if I can't see the FAQ to see what the site's about.

Comment: Let them read the FAQ?  I thought we had to force them to read it by kidnapping their loved ones!

Answer (score 1):

Did you commit to the site?  I'm okay with not displaying the FAQ publicly during the private beta; you can either check out the proposal on Area 51 — it hasn't been that long yet — or wait for the public beta phase — it's not that far away.

Comment: I didn't realize it was in Private Beta, how would you know looking at the front page?  There's nothing there to indicate it.

Comment: That's a reasonable point.  When I got my e-mail for the Web Apps private beta -- the first SE 2.0 site that got made -- I got the impression that discussing the site publicly was discouraged.  That discouragement wasn't followed in practice.  But the admins probably haven't made any changes to reflect that.

Comment: @Lance: You're right, I made [that a feature-request/bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63328/mark-a-private-beta-as-such-before-log-in).