# Mark a private beta as such *before* log in

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, login, private-beta

One may have received a link from a participant who forgot to mention that the site is still in its private beta. And a login suggest "accessible". Having the "this site is currently in private beta, you're to late to sign up" shown *after* creating an account is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible -- we don't know who you are until you attempt to log in.

We need to know if you're on the whitelist or not, and that requires you to authenticate (show some form of identification).

edit: I see your point now, and I've added

> Warning: this site is currently in **private beta** for (n) more days. Unless you committed to its [Area 51 site proposal](http://example.com), you won't be able to log in!

To the login page during the private beta period.

[image]

Comment: Well, just add a comment to the login page: Only people that committed to this page in Area51 are allowed in for the moment, as the site is in private beta. Come back in x days, if this is not you.

Comment: But currently, when I visit a private beta like http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, the title says "log in *or register*". So a new user would register not being aware of the privateness that you should at least *somehow* state somewhere. Those who are allowed know that they committed, so I second @Ralph

Comment: Some people may be directed to private betas not yet having an open ID and not having used SOFU so far, so how are they to know that they can't access the site anyway and then, when public, won't have to log in to "just browse"?