# Notify question OP (and those who marked it a favourite) if an answer has been modified

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, notifications, posts

Seriously, I had not noticed e.g. Jeff's edit [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63328/mark-a-private-beta-as-such-before-log-in/63342#63342) had he not also retagged my question.

Comment: If an edit is addressing something raised in a comment I often add another comment to point it out.

Comment: @ChrisF: true, but sometimes someone improves his/her answer with what (s)he considers a minor detail but which can turn out to be the missing link for the question asker

Comment: Edit notifications would be especially handy for [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: I'm all in favor for notifications. Allow me going *a bit* far to explain why: I believe the internet is so good today because of the excessive amount of information and the great filtering of that to our specific need at a specific time. And that, to me, is what google is to the internet just like what gmail is to emails and equally like a missing SE filter is to notifications. Finally, that's why I miss instant e-mail notification so much! :P

Comment: Tob, I was hoping it would go back to **you**! But you don't need to ask *me* twice to elaborate on anything... :P

Comment: @Cawas: nope, bounties will under no normal circumstances be refunded (not even by awarding it to own answers which you can therefore consider a slap in the face of every other answer)

Comment: I think this could provide a meaningful improvement to the Stack Overflow system. I have at least once already answered my own question, only to get a comment from someone else who answered my question and has edited their answer that I've essentially stolen their answer because I didn't notice the answer has been rewritten, and didn't get a notification of it. If I had gotten a notification, it would have saved me the embarassment of doing something stupid like that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Allow me to try a reasoning on why this (and [a sharper e-mail notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40927/how-do-you-do-to-keep-track-of-notifications)) should get implemented.

I believe the internet is so good today because of the excessive amount of information and the great filtering on top of that which fits our specific need at any specific time.

That is what google is to the internet.

Just like what gmail is to emails.

And what a still-non-existent-SEN filter would be to notifications.

Sure, Google is the home to our beloved StackExchange Network, but as I increase my contribution it becomes harder and harder to keep track of it. To the point I can't any longer always find stuff I've participated in.

By keeping a centralized place with all our contribution (which this suggestion helps to add) it does facilitate the process. By having all that data on gmail also helps a lot. It's both a healthy redundancy and a second option to google search.

<sub>And, while it doesn't relate to the whole reasoning I presented here, it wouldn't hurt to also get [instant notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/instant-e-mail-notifications-of-answers-to-questions/31596#31596) there as a bonus! (sorry, I can't help myself to stop insisting on this)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

So, is this implemented now? I get a notification for https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/7931/revisions,
[image: edit notification]
but according to comments on [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/146482) this doesn't seem to work for answer edits. Maybe that is [status-bydesign], but I would prefer notification on all edits concerning my own questions and favourites (unless the fav-notification pref is unchecked).

Comment: correct, it only works for answer edits or posts you otherwise *directly* own.

Comment: @Jeff: Couldn't this be changed to also include other posts (as option)? Edits might be a significant reason to e.g. change ones vote due to a fixed error

Comment: if it was handled accept your answer so that Mr. Community won't keep bumping this question. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: as Jeff replied, currently only direct owners are notified while an edited answer to ones questions still remains unnoticed unless you check back manually (which one does even less now what with relying on notifications and all...), so I'd say the feature-request is still open

Comment: The latest [explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84374/how-to-access-all-of-my-favorites/84387#84387) of the current notifications for favorite questions: *new answers were added, or new comments on the question. As if you owned the question you favorited.*, @Shadow.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to be notified when a post is edited, please use the [follow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/51) feature.

Comment: That feature wasn't available back then. But it's really too tedious and I don't want to manually follow all answers to my questions...

Comment: I wasn't aware of the "follow" feature until I read this answer. (I think it's a very nice and useful feature).