# Notify op if an answer has been updated

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notify question OP (and those who marked it a favourite) if an answer has been modified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64692/notify-question-op-and-those-who-marked-it-a-favourite-if-an-answer-has-been-mo)

I think if an answer has been updated, the op should get notified to see the updated answer.
Now I have to comment to the op with "see my updated answer" to get his attention.