# Does editing an answer show a notification to the asker

Tags: discussion, questions

Just really simple: If I post an answer to a question, and later add some important extra information, does the asker automatically get notified of the change in the answer, or do I need to leave a comment to the OP to alert the asker?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Sorry, my mistake, didn't read the question very carefully it seems. There's no notification for the asker.

Comment: @psubsee2003 please post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no notification to the question asker (aka OP) when an answer to their question is edited.  If you make a substantial enough change to the answer that may require the OP to be aware of the edit, you should ping them with an [`@` reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

If you are interested in such a feature, there is an existing feature request ([Notify question OP (and those who marked it a favourite) if an answer has been modified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64692/notify-question-op-and-those-who-marked-it-a-favourite-if-an-answer-has-been-m)), to notify the OP of edits, but it has not been implemented (and there is no way to know if it ever will be).